# Understand the whole process of function template overload resolution

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, overload-resolution

I found out that the overload resolution process is the more complicated I have ever learned in C++, Therefore, bear in mind that this topic is relatively difficult for me to understand easily, so be patient with me.

I have two examples here, and I tried to parse each example separately and understand what actually the compiler is doing starting from the call to the overloaded template until determining which overload is the best viable.

**First Example #1**

```
template <class T> void f(const T&); // F1: reference to const T
template <class T> void f(const T*); // F2: pointer to const T
f((int*)0);

// matching F1:
// deduction: P = const T&, A = int* --> const T& = int* --> T = int*
// instantiates: void f(int *const&); A = int*, P = int *const&
// S1 conversion: int* --> int* const& (identity conversion?)

// matching F2:
// P = const T*, A = int* --> const T* = int*; T = int;
// instantaies: void f(const int*); A = int*, P = const int*;
// S2 conversion: int* --> const int* (qualification conversion)
```

Per [[over.ics.rank]/3/3.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2)

> Standard conversion sequence `S1` is a better conversion sequence than
> standard conversion sequence `S2` if
>
> - (3.2.1) S1 is a proper subsequence
>   of `S2` (comparing the conversion sequences in the canonical form
>   defined by 12.2.4.2.2, excluding any Lvalue Transformation; the
>   identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any
>   non-identity conversion sequence)
> - [..]

`S1` is s a proper subsequence of `S2`: that's identity conversion is a proper subsequence of qualification conversion because the identity conversion sequence is considered to be a subsequence of any non-identity conversion sequence.

and per [[over.match.best.general]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-2):

> Given these definitions, a viable function `F1` is defined to be a
> better function than another viable function `F2` if for all arguments
> i, `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, and then
>
> - (2.1) — for some argument `j`, `ICSj(F1)` is a better conversion sequence than `ICSj(F2)`
> - [..]

Here, the implicit conversions for all arguments of `F1` (which is identity conversion) are "*not worse*" than the implicit conversions for all arguments of `F2` (which is qualification conversion), and there is at least one argument of `F1` whose implicit conversion is better than the corresponding implicit conversion for that argument of `F2`. Then the viable function `F1` is a better function than the viable function `F2`. Hence, a specialization of `F1` gets chosen by the overload resolution for the given call.

**My questions:**

- Have I parsed the whole process correctly?
- Does the compiler need to perform partial ordering at this point? if yes, why?, even though we knowfrom ICS that `F1` is the best viable candidate?

---

**Second Example #2**

```
template <class T> void f(const T&); // F1: reference to const T
template <class T> void f(T*);       // F2: pointer to T
f((int*)0);

// matching F1:
// deduction: P = const T&, A = int* --> const T& = int* --> T = int*
// instantiates: void f(int *const&); A = int*, P = int *const&
// S1 conversion: int* --> int* const& (identity conversion)

// matching F2:
// deduction: P = T*, A = int* --> T* = int*; T = int
// instantaies: void f(int*); A = int*, P = int*
// S2 conversion: int* --> int* (identity conversion)
```

Here neither rule in `[over.ics.rank]/3/3.2` is applied; that's both `S1` and `S2` are identity conversions.

Then the compiler goes to the next step to check the rules defined in [[over.match.best.general]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-2). Indeed `ICSi(F1)` is not a worse conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`, but the `2.1` bullet is not satisfied because `ICSi(F1)` is not a better conversion sequence than `ICSi(F2)`. The implicit conversion sequence for the argument of `F1` is actually the same (i.e not worse) as that of `F2`.

The compiler keeps checking the rules in [over.match.best.general]/2 until it hits bullet [2.5](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#general-2.5) which says:

> - [..]
> - (2.5) — F1 and F2 are function template specializations and the
>   function template for F1 is more specialized than the template for F2
>   according to the partial ordering rules [..]

I am not going through the whole process of partial ordering, instead, I will summarize things as possible.

Adjustment Function Signature:

```
void f(T);  // Tem1
void f(T*); // Tem2
```

Transformed Function Signature:

```
void f(U1);  // Tra1
void f(U2*); // Tra2
```

Matching `Tem1` against `Tran2`:

```
void f(T);  // Tem1
void f(U2*); // Tra2

// T = U2* - OK: T can be deduced from U2*
```

Matching `Tem2` against `Tran1`:

```
void f(T*); // Tem2
void f(U1);  // Tra1

// T* = U1 - error: T cannot be deduced
```

So template referred by `Tra2` is more specialized than the template referred by `Tran1`: `F2` is more specialized than `F1`. Therefore a specialization of `F2` will be selected by the overload resolution for the given call.

**My questions:**

- Have I parsed the whole process correctly?
- What I think (it might be incorrect) is that after template argument deduction, the compiler generates specializations for both overloads to match P/A pairs for the ICS process. Now does the compiler generates a specialization again for the more-specialized template?

---

Believe me, before posting this question, I searched a lot for a question that covers that whole process. What I need to know, Am I thinking right, and whether all quotes I provided are applied to the examples or not.

Sorry for taking long, and Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I found out that the overload resolution process is a more complicated topic than anything I ever learned in C++"_ - Don't tell anyone but I think that topic is pretty complicated too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Count me in/too :)

Comment: I've never learned the rules. While they are obviously important for compiler writers a jobbing programmer can get by on a few rules of thumb.

Comment: `const T& = int* --> T = int` doesn't compute. `T` must be `int*` here, with a temporary of type `int*` binding to a const reference of the same type; a qualification conversion. `void f(const int&)` is not callable with `int*` argument.

Comment: Thus, the signature deduced for F1 is `void f(int* const &)` , while for F2 it'ss `void f(const int*)`

Comment: I think F2 is preferred over F1 not because of implicit conversion sequences (they both involve qualified conversion), but because F2 is more specialized than F1, per **[temp.func.order]**

Comment: You made the same mistake in Example 2, where you somehow made a pointer indirection disappear (again, `int*` is not implicitly convertible to `const int&`). There, F1 needs qualification conversion while F2 is an exact match.

Comment: I'm with john here, and believe that you don't really need to handle all the details. Like in example #2, I can not even imagine a case where you would have a const reference and a non-const pointer, both being templates. Can you name a function that modifies the object when given a pointer, but not when given a reference? No? So then they would not be overloads. I think you are trying too hard here!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - "_again, int* is not implicitly convertible to const int&_" - This is reference binding according to [over.ics.ref]/1: "When a parameter of reference type binds directly to an argument expression, the implicit conversion sequence is the **identity conversion** [..]"

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - "_const T& = int* --> T = int doesn't compute. T must be int* here_" --- Good catch, but really unintended. You're right, this is just a typo and I edited it. Anyway, thanks, and feel free to edit the question to improve it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - "_I think F2 is preferred over F1, not because of implicit conversion sequences (they both involve qualified conversion)..._" Are you think? or sure?. I think (it could be wrong) this is just a reference binding that involves an identity conversion directly

Comment: I think you are right. You can play with [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/3d1jhj5P1) to see what compilers make of it, but here they agree on `f<int*>` and `g<int>`. Although even compiler writers do sometimes get things wrong, that is at least a good sign. I remember answering a similar question, but this process is possibly the most complicated part of the language and it's virtually impossible to keep all the details in memory.

Comment: Also, I think it's correct to speak of partial ordering in either case, because overload sets fit the mathematical definition of a partially ordered set. This just means that some pairs of candidates may be "incomparable": neither is a better match than the other. The wall of text you've read is basically the definition of the comparison relation between overloads. You could say, for example, that a non-template candidate is always ordered before a template specialisation, but extra steps are involved when both are templates.

Comment: Binding a non-const object to a const reference totally involves qualification conversion. Otherwise, you couldn't overload `void f(int&);` and `void f(const int&);` (the former wins when called with a non-const lvalue, because it's identity conversion while the latter requires qualification conversion).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik _Binding a non-const object to a const reference totally involves qualification conversion_ http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.ref#1.sentence-1 _Otherwise, you couldn't overload `void f(int&);` and `void f(const int&);`_  http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#3.2.6

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - "_I think F2 is preferred over F1 not because of implicit conversion sequences (they both involve qualified conversion), but because F2 is more specialized than F1, per [temp.func.order]_" Yeah F2 is more specialized than F1 but the compiler doesn't need to know that because ICS is enough to determine which one is better. It already knows that ICS(F1) is a better conversion than ICS(F2). Note that the compiler finally chooses F1 for the call `f((int*)0)`. **I am talking about the first example**

Comment: I like this question. _"Understand the whole process of function template overload resolution"_ - and I feel scared. _"What? No...."_